# Is it safe to remove AllItems.aspx from search crawling?

Tags: 2013, search

Every list or doclibrary has this page by default, is it safe to exclude it from crawling? will documents still be crawled if I exclude it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont affect the documents being crawled, only the allitems.aspx will not be crawled. If you are excluding Allitems.aspx using crawl rules, then after setting the rule, reset the index and do a full crawl. Resetting index and full crawl is not needed if you do it by Search Result webpart properties, as part of query option

```
{searchboxquery} -FileExtension:aspx
```

Comment: I have created a rule also to ignore the homepage of each site collection, we have 20.0000 site collection and the homepage is not content but just webparts showing documents from specific libraries which will be crawled anyway, so for us its not important that the homepage appears on search results,  however after removing the home.aspx with wildcard, I still see on my crawl log something like this, I wonder if I can also ignore this one without ignoring the enire site. http://screencast.com/t/yOSp4CF1

Answer (score 1):

Crawling SharePoint is typically done by SPS3 protocol (if specified in search source). This is default way for crawling and indexing SP. It does not rely on the content of default.aspx or any other SP page. It uses web services to analyze SP structure for crawling and indexing contained data. So excluding AllItems.aspx or Default.aspx does not affect crawled data except of the fact that these two pages will not be indexed.